# Getting latest memcached gem to build on Snow Leopard

Tags: ruby, memcached, rubygems

I've tried everything I can find on every website out there, and I can not get this to build.

```
$ ruby --version 
ruby 1.9.2p0 (2010-08-18 revision 29036) [x86_64-darwin10.4.0]
```

Full error: http://gist.github.com/651945

Entire build: http://gist.github.com/651952

Comment: what version of memcached are you running (`memcached -h`, check the first line)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just tried and was able to install memcached-1.0.1 using both ree and ruby1.9.2dev (via rvm). Can you try with the latest rvm and see if this makes a difference? Also check your toolchain (I'm on g++-4.2.1 that was bundled with mac developer tools, I believe). I have a system libmemcached in both /usr/local/{include,lib} and /opt/local/{include,lib}, and these aren't causing issues (and from your errors, it doesn't look like you're trying to link against the wrong library either).

I just tried with ruby-head: ruby 1.9.3dev (2010-10-29 trunk 29623) [x86_64-darwin10.4.0] and it's working as well.

How are you installing the gem? just `gem install memcached`?

Comment: $ g++ --version
i686-apple-darwin10-g++-4.2.1 (GCC) 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5664)

Comment: I've done both gem install memcached as well as bundle install (which just does the install of course).

Comment: rvm --version

rvm 1.0.16 by Wayne E. Seguin (wayneeseguin@gmail.com) [http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/]

Comment: I'll play around with a diff version of ruby I guess. Can't hurt to play around with those.

Comment: heh, I was still using 0.1.38, but just upgraded rvm and can still install memcached. I wouldn't think rvm would matter since it's correctly installing ruby and gem, so I'm hoping it's a ruby bug that's been fixed.

Comment: rvm install 1.9.2-head finally did it. Thanks Ben.